# Handle space of currentDir in batch file

Tags: command-line

If `%currentDir%` is appended with some paths name which contains spaces, the following error is obtained `"Error: Error occurred while opening or operating on file"`. But the same is working with static path like `"D:/Test Data/.."` where double quetes is used. But same is not working for dynamic path.

Please help me to resolve on this.

Here is my code:

```
ET currentDir= %cd%
sqlcmd -S %servername% -U %username% -P %password%  -d SBI_REPORTS_DB -i 
"%currentDir%/03_Performance_Report/03_P report - BG/Tables/SBI_BG_DATA_RPT_TB.sql"
```

Answer (score 0):

change `ET currentDir= %cd%` to

```
SET "currentDir=%cd%"
```